# Get item's URL with DropDelegate in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, ipados

I have a SwiftUI View conforming to `DropDelegate` and working correctly in order to receive images from other apps in `macOS` and `iPadOS`, but the behavior in both operative systems are quite different:

```
struct ContentView: View { 
    var body: some View {
        MyView { ... }
            .onDrop(of: [.fileURL, .image], delegate: self)
    }
}
```

And the `DropDelegate` implementation is:

```
extension ContentView: DropDelegate { 
   func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
      // Debug implementation
      if info.hasItemsConforming(to: [.image]) { 
         print("CONTAINS AN IMAGE")
      } else if info.hasItemsConforming(to: [.fileURL]) { 
         print("CONTAINS AN URL")
      }
   }
}
```

If I'm on `macOS` the output is `CONTAINS AN URL`, and if I'm on `iPadOS` the output is `CONTAINS AN IMAGE`.

The problem is that I need to access to some metadata (like the `creationDate`) of the source URL, and I cannot access to the `creationDate` if the output is an `UIImage`. How can I access to the source URL on iPadOS/iOS via DropDelegate? Or... How can I get the creationDate of an `UIImage` provided by `DropDelegate`?

Xcode 13 | macOS 12 | iPadOS 15 | Swift 5.5 | SwiftUI 3.0

Comment: Remove the `else`, does the iPad trigger with both image an URL? `DropInfo` can have multiple items, and this not only means that it can receive multiple items, it also means that an item may be represented in multiple ways.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Yes, I tried removing `else` and `[.image]` is only triggered on iPadOS, and `[.fileURL]` is only triggered on macOS. Also tried with `[.url]`

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? macOS seems not to work with types like .image or .audio or .video

Comment: Nope :(, on iPadOS you still get the data, not the url.